# Unkown directive in JS GraphQL

Tags: magento2, pwa, graphql, phpstorm

I'm experiencing the following issue in the graphql schema declaration in Magento2.
I use PhpStorm for development and, after installing the plugin **JS GraphQL**, it keeps prompting me errors on common directives as *@doc*, *@resolver*, ...

[image]

Does anyone know how to cope with this issue and let the plugin automatically recognize such directives as correct?

Thank you.

Comment: i guess this is not to warry about, You may proceed with the development.

Comment: It is not a problem for development indeed, it is a problem for the IDE I wanted to solve, but I figured out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trials, I found the way to solve this tedious problem. I report here my solution, hoping it would be useful for others encountering such issue.

First, you need to properly setup the config file for **JS GraphQL** (here mine, change the `url` according to your website location):

```
{
  "name": "Local Magento GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
  "excludes": ["dev/**"],
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://local.magento.it/graphql",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you've done with that, you'll get a popup asking you to introspect the schema. Introspect it and choose the path where to store the schema file.

[image]

Open the schema file, and add on top the following directive declarations:

```
directive @doc(description: String="") on QUERY
    | MUTATION
    | FIELD
    | FRAGMENT_DEFINITION
    | FRAGMENT_SPREAD
    | INLINE_FRAGMENT
    | SCHEMA
    | SCALAR
    | OBJECT
    | FIELD_DEFINITION
    | ARGUMENT_DEFINITION
    | INTERFACE
    | UNION
    | ENUM
    | ENUM_VALUE
    | INPUT_OBJECT
    | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION

directive @resolver(class: String="") on QUERY
    | MUTATION
    | FIELD
    | FRAGMENT_DEFINITION
    | FRAGMENT_SPREAD
    | INLINE_FRAGMENT
    | SCHEMA
    | SCALAR
    | OBJECT
    | FIELD_DEFINITION
    | ARGUMENT_DEFINITION
    | INTERFACE
    | UNION
    | ENUM
    | ENUM_VALUE
    | INPUT_OBJECT
    | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION

directive @typeResolver(class: String="") on INTERFACE | OBJECT

directive @cache(cacheIdentity: String="" cacheable: Boolean=true) on QUERY
```

Such declarations come from the `vendor/magento/module-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls` file. At this point, the error should be disappeared and the directives properly recognized.

[image]

That's it.